# What is this new indicator?

Tags: indicator

I have a new indicator in my top menu bar as shown below which I have no idea how it came there. The indicator shows a blank menu when I click it. Can anyone help what the indicator is about and how to hide it?
My OS is 16.10.
[image]

Comment: The red slashed circle indicates that the icon is missing.

Comment: What happens if you click on it? no info?